# string regex in between open close brackets in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string as follows,

```
String string = "background: transparent url(../../images/oracle-java-logo.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;"
```

I want to get only url value (../../images/oracle-java-logo.png).

So I am using String regex as follows, but I am getting only empty value for that regex

```
Pattern patternUrl = Pattern.compile(" url((.*?))", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
String string = "background: transparent url(../../images/oracle-java-logo.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;"

Matcher matcher = patternUrl.matcher(string);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Regex is--"+(matcher.group(1)));
}
```

it prints only Regex is--.

What is wrong in the above code? hope someone will assist in this

Comment: Try [`\(([^)]+)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/oN8tJ6/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pattern patternUrl = Pattern.compile("url(\\(([^)]+)\\))", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = patternUrl.matcher(string);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Regex is--"+(matcher.group(1)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
Pattern patternUrl = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        String string = "background: transparent url(../../images/oracle-java-logo.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;";

        Matcher matcher = patternUrl.matcher(string);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Regex is--"+(matcher.group(1)));
        }
```